# NSwag - create one client per API controller

Tags: openapi, nswag

I have a Web project with different API controllers.

When creating the client using NSwag, all methods from all controllers are put in the same API Client.

How could I get one ApiClient per API controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide code that you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

Put this in you nswag configuration under `codeGenerators.openApiToCSharpClient` ->
`"operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromOperationId"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `operationGenerationMode` in your nswag.json file to have the value `MultipleClientsFromOperationId`. See [here](https://github.com/DanielGasson/nswag-client-example) for an example project that generates a client class per API controller, specifically [here](https://github.com/DanielGasson/nswag-client-example/blob/master/Api/nswag.json#L90) for the option you need to change

Answer (score 0):

i know it's too late, but now i encountered a similiar problem
so the answer is
with  typescript client

```
"openApiToTypeScriptClient": {
      "operationGenerationMode": "MultipleClientsFromPathSegments",

.
}
```

this line make every controller a class in api